# Check column headers starting character

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dataframes. I want to loop through the column headers of each dataframe to make sure they start with a letter. If they do not start with a letter I will add the prefix "c_". How can I create the loop to check the first character of each string?

Here is the code for the dataframes:

```
import os
import glob

files = glob.glob(os.path.join("staging" + "/*.csv"))

print(files)

# Create an empty dictionary to hold the dataframes from csvs
dict_ = {}

# Write the files into the dictionary
for file in files:
    fname = os.path.basename(file)
    fname = fname.replace('.csv', '')
    dict_[fname] = pd.read_csv(file, header = 0, dtype = str, encoding = 'cp1252').fillna('')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`Index.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.where.html) with mask created by `str[0]` for select first character and [`isalpha`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isalpha.html) for check non numbers because `Index.mask` is not implemented yet:

```
df.columns = df.columns.where(df.columns.str[0].str.isalpha(), 'c_' + df.columns)
```

Solution in loop:

```
for file in files:
    fname = os.path.basename(file)
    fname = fname.replace('.csv', '')
    dict_[fname] = pd.read_csv(file, header = 0, dtype = str, encoding = 'cp1252').fillna('')
    mask = dict_[fname].columns.str[0].str.isalpha()
    dict_[fname].columns = dict_[fname].columns.where(mask, 'c_' + dict_[fname].columns)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1A':list('abcdef'),
                   '3df':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   '34F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
  1A 34F  3df  C  D  E
0  a   a    4  7  1  5
1  b   a    5  8  3  3
2  c   a    4  9  5  6
3  d   b    5  4  7  9
4  e   b    5  2  1  2
5  f   b    4  3  0  4

df.columns = df.columns.where(df.columns.str[0].str.isalpha(), 'c_' + df.columns)
print (df)
  c_1A c_34F  c_3df  C  D  E
0    a     a      4  7  1  5
1    b     a      5  8  3  3
2    c     a      4  9  5  6
3    d     b      5  4  7  9
4    e     b      5  2  1  2
5    f     b      4  3  0  4
```

Similar solution with [`isdigit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html) and invert mask by `~`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.where(~df.columns.str[0].str.isdigit(), 'c_' + df.columns)
print (df)
  c_1A c_34F  c_3df  C  D  E
0    a     a      4  7  1  5
1    b     a      5  8  3  3
2    c     a      4  9  5  6
3    d     b      5  4  7  9
4    e     b      5  2  1  2
5    f     b      4  3  0  4
```

Comment: The only thing I dont understand is how it is appending non-alpha columns because "mask" = .isalpha() = True....but I checked the files manually in the database and they have been appended

Comment: It works, because `where` works  if `False`  values. So if **not** alpha value add suffix.